# Can't select faces

Tags: faces, selection-tools, error

I am a practically new user of blender, and I have been encountering that error many times.Sometimes I can't select specific faces of a mesh no matter how hard I try.Circle, box, vertices selection, none of that seems to work. Have someone already figure how to solve that?

[image]

Comment: You are in *Vertex Selection Mode*, not face selection, so a face will only be selected after all its bounding vertex are selected. That probably means you have duplicate geometry or overlapping vertex there. Ty using `W`> Remove doubles.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much. I read need to read again the help section. Thanks again.